# Time gap between meal and stretching exercise?

Tags: stretching

I always wonder to know what should be the time gap between meal and specifically stretching exercises.

So

1. After how many hours of meal I should not do stretching?
2. And after how many hours of stretching exercise I should not take anything in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read if you are going to exercise but you have just eaten a meal, wait at least 2 hours. If you had something lighter, a snack perhaps, less of a wait is fine. As far as exercising before you eat, in my experience you can eat right after you exercise. I am not usually hungry until about 30 minutes after I eat, but it's probably because I like to drink a couple glasses of water after an intense workout.

If you are just doing stretching exercises that don't work up a sweat, I'd say do your exercises whenever you want. If you aren't doing something that is going to dramatically increase your heart rate, eating before or after isn't really going to hurt anything.

Comment: Thanks @jlg, I have a question that, yes it doesn't increase my heart rate or doesn't feel me like heavy exercise but still when I stretch I feel that my complete abdominal muscles are also stretching so is it really alright to do stretching after meal?

Comment: If it's a complete meal and you don't feel comfortable stretching, wait maybe 15-20 minutes and see how you feel then. Everytime I stretch I can feel my abs stretching too. They are also just muscles and need stretching sometimes. You could always just stretch before the meal, if your ab muscles feel like they are getting too much, maybe it's just the type of stretching that you are doing that is causing them to work harder than normal.